# nested sequences to branching/tree data structure

Tags: haskell, clojure, f#, ocaml

I'm not sure if this is an easy problem to solve and I am just missing something obvious, but I have been banging my head against it for sometime. I am trying to express tree divergence using lists. This is so I can easily specify my dataset easily inline using simple primitives, not worry about order, and build the tree from a disperate set of lists later.

So I have some lists like this:

```
 a = ["foo", "bar", "qux"]
 b = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
 c = ["qux", "bar", "qux"]
```

I would like to have a function, that would take a sequence of these lists and express a tree like so:

```
myfunc :: [[a]] -> MyTree a

(root) -> foo -> bar -> [baz, qux]
       -> qux -> bar -> qux
```

An ideal solution would be able to take sequences of varying lengths, i.e:

```
a = ["foo"; "bar"; "qux"]
b = ["foo"; "bar"; "baz"; "quux"]
== 
(root) -> foo -> bar -> [qux, baz -> quux]
```

Are there any textbook examples or algorithms that can help me with this? seems like it can be solved elegantly, but all my stabs at it look absolutely horrible!

Please feel free to post a solution in any functional language, I will translate it as appropriate.

Thanks!

Comment: Note - the data structure you are wanting to build is a _Trie_ - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I approached this problem was to use a `Forest` to represent your type and then make a `Forest` a `Monoid`, where `mappend`ing two `Forest`s together joins their common ancestors.  The rest is just coming up with a suitable `Show` instance:

```
import Data.List (sort, groupBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Foldable (foldMap)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Monoid

data Tree a = Node
    { value :: a
    , children :: Forest a
    } deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance (Show a) => Show (Tree a) where
    show (Node a f@(Forest ts0)) = case ts0 of
        []  -> show a
        [t] -> show a ++ " -> " ++ show t
        _   -> show a ++ " -> " ++ show f

data Forest a = Forest [Tree a] deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance (Show a) => Show (Forest a) where
    show (Forest ts0) = case ts0 of
        []  -> "[]"
        [t] -> show t
        ts  -> show ts

instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Forest a) where
    mempty = Forest []
    mappend (Forest tsL) (Forest tsR) =
          Forest
        . map (\ts -> Node (value $ head ts) (foldMap children ts))
        . groupBy ((==) `on` value)
        . sort
        $ tsL ++ tsR

fromList :: [a] -> Forest a
fromList = foldr cons nil
  where
    cons a as = Forest [Node a as]
    nil = Forest []
```

Here's some example usage:

```
>>> let a = fromList ["foo", "bar", "qux"]
>>> let b = fromList ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"]
>>> a
"foo" -> "bar" -> "qux"
>>> b
"foo" -> "bar" -> "baz" -> "quux"
>>> a <> b
"foo" -> "bar" -> ["baz" -> "quux","qux"]
>>> a <> a
"foo" -> "bar" -> "qux"
```

So your `myFunc` would become:

```
myFunc :: [[a]] -> Forest a
myFunc = foldMap fromList
```

Comment: Thank you @gabriel-gonzalez an excellent answer, very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a solution that is very similar to Gabriel's, but my data representation uses a `Map` so that I can load off most of the work to `Data.Map.unionWith`.

```
import Data.Map (Map, empty, singleton, unionWith, assocs)
import Data.Monoid

type Path a = [a]
data Tree a = Tree {leaf :: Bool, childs :: Map a (Tree a)} deriving Show
```

The boolean flag in the trees marks whether this node can be the end of a path. The `a`values are hidden inside the `childs` Map. To warm up, let's define how to convert a single path into a tree.

```
root :: Tree a
root = Tree True empty

cons :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a
cons node tree = Tree False (singleton node tree)

follow :: Path a -> Tree a
follow = foldr cons root
```

The `follow` function is called `fromList` in Gabriel's code. We can also enumerate all paths that are contained in a tree.

```
paths :: Tree a -> [Path a]
paths (Tree leaf childs) =
  (if leaf then [[]] else []) ++
  [ node : path | (node, tree) <- assocs childs, path <- paths tree ]
```

The questions essentially asks for an inverse of this `paths` function. Using `unionWith`, we can define the monoid structure of trees easily.

```
instance Ord a => Monoid (Tree a) where
  mempty = Tree False empty
  mappend (Tree leaf1 childs1) (Tree leaf2 childs2) = Tree leaf childs where
    leaf = leaf1 || leaf2
    childs = unionWith mappend childs1 childs2
```

Now to convert a list of paths to a tree, we just use `mconcat` and `follow`.

```
unpaths :: Ord a => [Path a] -> Tree a
unpaths = mconcat . map follow
```

Here is a test case using the paths from the question.

```
a, b, c, d :: Path String

a = ["foo", "bar", "qux"]
b = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
c = ["qux", "bar", "qux"]
d = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"]

-- test is True
test = (paths . unpaths) [a, b, c, d] == [b, d, a, c]
```

We get the same paths back that we stored in the tree, but as an ordered list.

Comment: I have to say this solution is pretty awesome as well. Thanks!

Comment: If leaf then it should not have any child and this can be represented using sum type : `data Tree a = Leaf | Children Map a (Tree a) deriving Show`

Comment: @Ankur That wouldn't work if some of the paths end early. For example, in `unpaths [[1], [1, 2]]` the node labeled with `1` is both a leaf (for the first path) and it has children (for the second path). So this datatype is not really a tree, more like an infinite state automaton.

Answer (score 1):

```ml
type TreeNode<'T> = 
  | Node of 'T * Tree<'T>
and Tree<'T> = TreeNode<'T> list

module Tree =
  let rec ofList = function
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> [Node(x, ofList xs)]

  let rec merge xs tree =
    match (tree, xs) with
    | _, [] -> tree
    | [], _ -> ofList xs
    | nodes, x::xs ->
      let matching, nonMatching = nodes |> List.partition (fun (Node(y, _)) -> y = x)
      match matching with
      | [Node(_, subtree)] -> Node(x, merge xs subtree) :: nonMatching
      | _ -> Node(x, ofList xs)::nodes

Tree.ofList ["foo"; "bar"; "qux"]
|> Tree.merge ["foo"; "bar"; "baz"]
|> Tree.merge ["qux"; "bar"; "qux"]

> val it : TreeNode<string> list =
  [Node ("qux",[Node ("bar",[Node ("qux",[])])]);
   Node ("foo",[Node ("bar",[Node ("baz",[]); Node ("qux",[])])])]
```

Answer (score 0):

A clojure version, using hashmaps:

```
(defn merge-to-tree
  [& vecs]
  (let [layer (group-by first vecs)]
    (into {} (map (fn [[k v]]
                    (when k
                      [k (apply merge-to-tree (map rest v))]))
                  layer))))
```

Here I am using group-by to see when multiple vector elements should be represented by a single item in the output structure. `(into {} (map (fn [[k v]] ...) m))` is a standard idiom for destructuring hash entries, performing some operations, then reconstructing a hash from the result. The recursive call on the values `(apply merge-to-tree (map rest v))` constructs the various branches below that layer of the tree structure (map rest, because the full input is preserved by group-by, and the first element has already been used as the lookup key).

I welcome other suggestions / improvements. Example usage:

```
user> (merge-to-tree ["foo" "bar" "qux"])
{"foo" {"bar" {"qux" {}}}}

user> (merge-to-tree ["foo" "bar" "qux"] ["foo" "bar" "baz"] ["qux" "bar" "qux"])
{"foo" {"bar" {"qux" {}, "baz" {}}}, "qux" {"bar" {"qux" {}}}}

user> (merge-to-tree ["foo" "bar" "qux"] ["foo" "bar" "baz" "quux"])
{"foo" {"bar" {"qux" {}, "baz" {"quux" {}}}}}
```